# Animating UITableView’s auto layout top constraint resulting in crash, any clue?

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash, uiviewanimation, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` like this -

[image]

and i am adjusting this `tblViewTopConstraint` with animation in `UIScrollView's delegate` -

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Animation Code -

```
[self.tblViewTopConstraint setConstant:45.0f];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [self.tblView.superview layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
```

Animation is working fine but if i scroll UITableView up/down 5-6 times, it suddenly throwing this crash -

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xa75abb0 h=--& v=--& XYZCustomCell:0xb4c6f00.width == UITableViewWrapperView:0xb4bb710.width> view:<UITableViewWrapperView: 0xb4bb710; frame = (0 0; 320 459); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xb4ca150>>'
```

Comment: I imagine you are trying to animate a nav bar or header on and off screen when user scrolls up or down -- a la Facebook. I'm trying the exact same approach and my animation is working, but the tableview flashes white during my animated layout if needed as it grows in height. Did you ever see this in yours?

Comment: @JasonC.Howlin Yes i am animating a view (look's like in header) as twitter does, but my doesn't flashes.

Comment: Thanks! Also, Im finding that with this approach the table is moving from underneath the user's finger slightly. Have you noticed this to be a problem to your users?

Answer (score 0):

The error says, that the constraint, causing the crash is a width constraint:

```
constraint:<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xa75abb0 h=--& v=--& XYZCustomCell:0xb4c6f00.width == UITableViewWrapperView:0xb4bb710.width>
```

so I don't think your problem is with the animation or with that particular constraint.